# How can i debug an ios app file (.ipa)?

Tags: ios, debugging, ipa

I'm not so much familiar to ios development.
I Build an ios app cloud base and i have a .ipa file, the app doesn't work well. Is there anyway to debug the .ipa file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once you have build the .ipa file you no longer able to debug it. but you can debug it from the source code in xcode before archiving the project. And now apple provided us with a way to debug without paying those 99$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging an IOS app requires an IOS developer license, that costs about 99/year. I am not an expert but if you already have this license you should be able to put your app in your iphone or ipad and debug-test it on native hardware.

Comment: is there anyway to debug it with xcode or something like this?

Comment: You debug the program using XCode, but you will need the source code project from which the app ws compiled. Although you can attach the debugger to any process running in the device, without he source code and debug symbols it will be pretty hard to see what is going on - and even if you do find issues, without the source code you can't fix them

Comment: @Paulw11 you say there is no way to debug the .ipa file?

Comment: What would be the point without the source?  You couldn't fix any problems anyway